# Beagleboard-xm only boots to command line prompt

Tags: beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I recently purchased a beagleboard-xm and i've been trying to get it to boot into Angstrom.

I followed the instructions on Trey Weaver's blog (http://treyweaver.blogspot.com/2010/10/installing-angstrom-on-beagleboard-xm.html), and was able to get my Beagleboard to boot to the point where it offers me the commandline login screen:

```
.-------.                                           
|       |                  .-.                      
|   |   |-----.-----.-----.| |   .----..-----.-----.
|       |     | __  |  ---'| '--.|  .-'|     |     |
|   |   |  |  |     |---  ||  --'|  |  |  '  | | | |
'---'---'--'--'--.  |-----''----''--'  '-----'-'-'-'
                -'  |
                '---'

The Angstrom Distribution beagleboard ttyS2

Angstrom 2010.7-test-20110220 beagleboard ttyS2

beagleboard login:
```

However, I want to boot into the graphical interface so that I can play videos on the beagleboard.

I found a second tutorial (http://guillaume.segu.in/blog/hackens/337/getting-started-with-your-brand-new-beagleboard-xm/) that suggested making a boot.scr file to boot into the OS properly.  I have tried that, but to no avail.

How do I get the beagleboard to boot properly into the full OS instead of just the commandline version?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your specific distro, but the usual Unix way to specify "boot to GUI" is via [runlevels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel). If the distro defaults to runlevel 3 (text), you might log in and ask to switch to runlevel 5 (gui) with `telinit 5`.

If that works, then you can change the default. On older systems, the default is stored in `/etc/inittab`.

If that doesn't work, check that you actually have X11 installed on your Angstrom distro.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- could you elaborate?